# React ternary operation for useState()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React. I have the following setup to initialise my component's state based on a condition, using a ternary operation.

```
const defaultValue = ['bar']
const myComponent = ({data}) => {

 const foo = (data) => {
   // ...
 }
 const [values, setValues] = Object.keys(data).length > 0 ? useState(foo(data)): useState(defaultValue);

 return (<Comp state={values} />);

}
export default myComponent
```

The idea is that the initial state will be dependent on the variable 'data' if it is not empty, otherwise it will be assigned a default value. It is now assumed that 'data' is not empty.

I have it that foo() is being called when I expect it, and the argument, data, is also as I expect. If I log the array that foo returns, it is exactly as I want. Unfortunately, when I log 'state' from inside the Comp component, it is the defaultValue.

If I add a console.log("renders") towards the top of myComponent, I get that printout twice, which I suspect is part of the problem?

If this setup is unconventional please let me know and I'll refactor, but if there is a simple work around that somebody is aware of, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to give better advice without seeing a bit more code. However, you can use a [functional value](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state) to initialize the state:

```js
const defaultValue = ['bar'];

const MyComponent = ({data}) => {
  const foo = (data) => {
    // ...
  };

  const [values, setValues] = useState(() => Object.keys(data).length > 0 ? foo(data) : defaultValue);

  return (<Comp state={values} />);
}
```

Or just modify the `foo` closure to fulfill that purpose:

```js
const defaultValue = ['bar'];

const MyComponent = ({data}) => {
  const foo = () => {
    if (Object.keys(data).length === 0) return defaultValue;
    // ...
  };

  const [values, setValues] = useState(foo);
  return (<Comp state={values} />);
}
```

Using this form has the additional benefit of preventing `foo` from being invoked needlessly on every render of your component.

Comment: Thank you for giving me this feedback, I got it working. I was not aware of that second form, thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

The code has a problem because `useState` is used inside a ternary condition

```
Object.keys(data).length > 0 ? useState(foo(data)): useState(defaultValue);
```

We shouldn't `useState` hook inside any condition check because it'll affect the component rendering as seen in the doc.

To solve the problem

```
const initialValue = Object.keys(data).length > 0 ? foo(data) : defaultValue;
const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValue);
```

[image]

Ref:

https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/state-a-components-memory#meet-your-first-hook

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out for me. It makes sense to initialise the state before the hook, I'll make sure to follow this going forward.